# I cannot reach the result in C# or Crystal Reports but I can in SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server, crystal-reports-2008

This is my query

```
select sum(Totals) 
from store_in 
where ItemDate between '2018-10-26' and '2018-10-26'
```

I can use this in SQL Server and get results, but in C# and Crystal Reports, I don't know how can I get the results.

I'm using an ADO.NET connection

the problem is 
just I wanna get sum(Totals) column in C# and send it to Crystal Report 
or get sum(Totals) in Crystal Report
and the ItemDate Data type is Varchar(50) the comparison  in Crystal Report doesn't work

Comment: Could you show us your c# code?

Comment: the problem is 
just I wanna get sum(Totals) column in C# and send it to Crystal Report 
or get sum(Totals) in Crystal Report
and the ItemDate Data type is Varchar(50) the comparison  in Crystal Report doesn't work

Comment: How are you reading the data in C#?  As stated this is somewhat unclear since you have multiple objectives stated and no code related to the "stated" desire here.

Comment: "ItemDate Data type is Varchar(50)" so the SQL would not work in that case...note that a "between" with the same date (no time) is really an "equal" in SQL.  Please clarify a lot more here as the details are not really clear.

Answer (score 2):

Give the output column an alias and reference that column name when reading the putput:

```
select sum(Totals) AS Total
from store_in
...
```

Since there are LOTS of ways to read data in C#, there's not a way to give a comprehensive example, but in general you'd just reference is like it was an actual column in a table.